# Relation between function type (T1,T2,..,Tn) -> R and the interface FunctionN

Tags: kotlin

Would it be correct to say that a function type in the form `(T1,T2,..,Tn) -> R` is always interpreted **on the JVM**, as the [interface](https://github.com/JetBrains/kotlin/blob/1.2.70/libraries/stdlib/jvm/runtime/kotlin/jvm/functions/Functions.kt) `Function[n]<T1,T2,..,Tn,R>` ?

**Edit:** A writeup of [what I learned](https://sorokod.github.io/post/2018-09-09-kotlin-functions-as-objects/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, mostly. The `FunctionN` interfaces are the JVM back-end representation for the function types.

One correction is that the `(T1, T2, ..., Tn) -> R` type is represented by `Function[n]<T1, T2, ...Tn, R>`, not `Function[n + 1]<...>`.

This is true for functions with 22 or less parameters, while functions with 23 and more parameters are all represented with a single special interface.

You can find some notes on the design in this spec document: [(link)](https://github.com/JetBrains/kotlin/blob/master/spec-docs/function-types.md)

Comment: Thanks, I amended my question.

Comment: I am curious about _functions with 23 and more parameters are all represented with a single special interface_. If I define `f(p1:Int,.., p23:Int) = ""` the call to `::f` generates a runtime exception `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: kotlin/Function23` which makes sense as the `Function[n]` interface go only up to `Function22`

Comment: @DavidSoroko, oh, it seems like that's not properly supported yet, see [KT-13764](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-13764).

Comment: @DavidSoroko, you can try Kotlin the 1.3-M1 early access preview, it should work then.